# Javascript encoding test for url?

Tags: php, javascript

I need to send data via a url (it's JSON'd) that I would like to encrypt using some method that I can then decrypt it using php. I was thinking base64, but I need a url safe base 64 (I'm using CI and CI removes +,= and /).

Is there anyway to duplicate

```
function url_base64_encode(&$str="")
{
    return strtr(
            base64_encode($str),
            array(
                '+' => '.',
                '=' => '-',
                '/' => '~'
            )
        );
}
```

in Javascript?

Or some other alternative?

Comment: Encryption != Encoding. Do not think you're securely transferring data here.

Comment: I know, but I'd much rather send it as a bunch of garbage then send it as form_id = 5... I know if someone was to take the time to decrypt it, etc they could access it. But it's better then having them just be able to change a #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jCryption maybe what you are looking for: http://www.jcryption.org/

Comment: Don't be a rep farm, if your answer is high quality, you will be upvoted and accepted. +1 btw, great answer :)